Нужна ли запятая перед И в предложении ниже?
Хочется получить правильные ответы и чтобы все серьёзно отнеслись к задаче.

Правильно:
Хочется получить правильные ответы и чтобы все серьёзно отнеслись к задаче.
Пояснение
Предложение интересное! С одной стороны, классики часто использовали такую грамматику, с другой стороны, в некоторых современных источниках подобные структуры названы некорректными.
Разговорная грамматика? Дискуссионный  вопрос.
 Такие предложения достаточно часто встречаются в 
 классической и современной литературе, причем их 
 можно объяснить.В этих случаях более сложная 
 конструкция (предложение, оборот речи) выступает в 
 качестве  структурного элемента (например, одного 
 слова) при построении другой конструкции.Это 
 явление можно назвать к о н т а м и н а ц и е й 
 (лат. contaminatio «смешение»), и оно не редкость 
 в русской грамматике.

Я думал уж о форме плана и как героя назову (А.С.Пушкин).
Примеры из классической литературы:
Приезжай завтра или когда тебе будет удобно.
На мгновение чуть не позабыли Настасью Филипповну и что всё- 
таки она хозяйка своего вечера.
Он пробормотал ей в ответ что-то неопределённое о каких-то 
справках и что всё это, конечно, нелепость.
Его дядя, в наказание себе И чтобы не быть эгоистом, всё 
более и более присылал ему денег.

Можно посмотреть статью на тему и сделать выводы.

Не то. Нет ни одного примера и инфинитивами как в вопросе у автора.

Лучше всего поставьте перед "и" длинное тире:

Хочется получить правильные ответы — и чтобы все серьёзно отнеслись к
задаче.

Вы так  связь с "хочется" сохраните и переход разграничите. Потому что спорить можно как в пользу запятой, так и против. А здесь всё при деле.
